# Enable downloading from my web site

Tags: asp.net, download

I have a web site application and i need my web site to allow user to download a setup file from my web site how can i do this ?

I Asp.net2.0 _ C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the file somewhere within your website and make a link to it:

```
<a href="/downloads/setup.msi">Click here to download</a>
```

If a simple links does not work, please update your question with a description of the problem you are facing. You might have to configure your web server to serve files of type MSI or EXE (whatever your installer is packaged as).